# How to convert an edge into a curved edge?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, edges

I need to curve a single edge of a plane.
I tried vertex bevel but either it didn't work or I did some mistake.

The plane I have:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

The shape I want:

[image: 3]

As can be seen in above images I need to curve only one edge of a traingular shape plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we lack informations about what's the final goal, for example are you supposed to extrude, smooth, etc?

But if you want a simple flat shape, you can round the corners this way:

- Delete the faces with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Only Faces*.
- Select the vertices that are supposed to be round.
- Press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel. Press <kbd>+</kbd> to increase the amount of segments, or do it on the bottom of the *Tools* panel (on the left of your 3D view).
- Now fill the whole mesh with an <kbd>F</kbd>.
- Finish the mesh with some additional vertices and edges if necessary, the knife tool is convenient for this purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

thats easier. just add some egde loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> here i added 7, then select both of the middle ones and scale <kbd>S</kbd> them in this case i scale them in the <kbd>X</kbd> axis, then select the first,the middle,and the last vertices and then enable an addon called looptools and then save user settings, and then press <kbd>W</kbd> key and select looptools, curve, then press <kbd>T</kbd> to see the settings and lock in this case the <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> axis only and then repeat the same in the other faces and you are done.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The markdown for keyboard keys is `<kbd>T</kbd>`

Comment: @batFINGER ahhh you mean to write that and it would appear the keyboard keys, like in the upper post, thanks dude